# Sorting non-numeric objects with limited data

Tags: sorting

Say I have non-numeric objects that can sometimes be compared, but sometimes there is no data for the comparison.

For example:

- `A` is greater than `B`, but does not compare against C.
- `B` is greater than `C`.

This clearly creates a sorted list of `A`, `B`, `C`.

However, let's add `D` which is greater than `C`.  Since there is no data comparing `D` to either `A` or `B` the final rank is not clear.

What I'm looking for is a way to rank these types of data points with a "best effort", knowing that there is limited data and the final sorted list will only be partially sorted.

Also, I'm open to representing this other than a one dimensional array. Some sort of tree, perhaps?

Another idea is to group data points with lots of data together, since they can be sorted easily.  Then use inter-group comparison to rank the groups.  The problem with this is that sometimes a data point would compare well against multiple groups.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember university correctly, this is usually done with a graph algorithm. Make a directed graph of all items where the edge goes from a greater element to a lesser element, and keep track of how many incoming edges a node has. Remove a node with no incoming edges from the graph - decrementing the incoming edge count for all nodes the removed node was pointing at - rinse, repeat. For the details and algorithm hints, research [topological sorting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

If at any point you end up with a nonempty graph where all nodes have an incoming edge, your ordering has a cycle in it and thus is not an ordering.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.  I will keep the question open until I get a chance to try it, in case anyone else has other ideas.  I have a feeling there will be loops though.

Comment: Assuming I get a loop, maybe I can flatten that group into one item, then proceed.  Then at the end expand the group again.

Comment: I think that's provably not going to help - the loop will be between the items in the group - but it's like 4am here so don't hold me too strongly to that.

Comment: Yeah, it's ok if some are tied, and long as I can place that in the overall list.